# Mule- Extracting key from Json object using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I need to extract key and values from json input object to form different json output.

I went through the documentation and other questions asked similar to this where I could found out that $$ gives the key but, in my case it is giving me index but not the key name.

The input json looks like this :`{
"key2": "val2",
"key3": "val3",
"key4": "val4",
"key5": "val5",
"key6": "val6"
}`

The dataweave code I have written is :

```
{
"someOtherKey": "val",
properties: {
    entry: payload map

     {  
        key:$$,
        value:$
     }


}
```

}

After transformation I am getting :

```
{
 "someOtherKey": "val",
"properties": {
    "entry": [
        {
            "key": 0,
            "value": "val2"
        },
        {
            "key": 1,
            "value": "val3"
        },
        {
            "key": 2,
            "value": "val4"
        },
        {
            "key": 3,
            "value": "val5"
        },
        {
            "key": 4,
            "value": "val6"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Here I am expecting output with key name as value for **Key**

Expected output :

```
{
"someOtherKey": "val",
"properties": {
    "entry": [{
            "key": "key2",
            "value": "val2"
        },
        {
            "key": "key3",
            "value": "val3"
        },
        {
            "key": "key4",
            "value": "val4"
        },
        {
            "key": "key5",
            "value": "val5"
        },
        {
            "key": "key6",
            "value": "val6"
        }

    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag **pluck** worked for me. Here is the example  :

```
{
"someOtherKey": "val",
properties: {
    entry: payload pluck

     {  
        key:$$,
        value:$
     }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mapObject`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-operators#map-object) instead of `map`

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    key: "val",
    key1: "val1",
    properties: {
        entry: payload mapObject {  
            key:$$,
            value:$
         }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but, this gives me only one :{
   "someOtherKey": "val",
    "properties": {
        "entry": {
            "key": "key6",
            "value": "val6"
        }
    }
}